# how to pass a list in a predicate in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to store a paragram as a list in a variable and then call that list for counting how many times a particular word appears in that paragraph.

However, when I do this:

```
L = [hello,hello,hello].

counthowmany(_, [], 0) :- !.
counthowmany(X, [X|Q], N) :- !, counthowmany(X, Q, N1), N is N1+1.
counthowmany(X, [_|Q], N) :- counthowmany(X, Q, N).
```

... and compile buffer, and then ask this:

```
counthowmany(hello,L,N).
```

The number of "hello" occurrences in the list doesn't show, instead I receive a warning:

```
singleton variable:[X]
```

Comment: i don't want to use any list in the question ...... i just want to store a paragraph as a list in a variable and want to call that list for counting how many times a particular word appeared in that paragraph but when i do this "X = [hello,hello,hello]." and write the following code "counthowmany(_, [], 0) :- !. counthowmany(X, [X|Q], N) :- !, counthowmany(X, Q, N1), N is N1+1. counthowmany(X, [_|Q], N) :- counthowmany(X, Q, N)." and compile buffer i have a warning singleton variable:[X] and when i ask in prolog "counthowmany(hello,X,N)." the number of hello in the list doesn't shows

Comment: If you would like to encourage additional assistance, please update your question (click `edit`) with any details and don't use comments to list code. It's very hard to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line in a prolog file:

```
L = [hello,hello,hello].
```

Means to prolog:

```
=(L, [hello,hello,hello]).
```

Which means you're attempting to define a predicate, `=/2`. So not only will you get a singleton warning about `L` (since `L` isn't used anywhere else in this predicate definition), but you'll also see an error about an attempt to re-define the built-in `=/2` since prolog already has it defined.

What you can do instead is:

```
my_list([hello,hello,hello]).
```

Then later on, you can do:

```
my_list(L), counthowmany(hello,L,N).
```

Note that this case works:

```
L = [hello,hello,hello], counthowmany(hello,L,N).
```

It works because it's not attempting to *re-define* `=/2`. It is just *using* the existing built-in predicate `=/2`.

Comment: hope i can get some further assistance .......

""my_list(L), counthowmany(hello,L,N)."" now this is my question and if i want to insert this question in a rule like 
""numberofhello :- my_list(L), counthowmany(hello,L,N)."" and just ask numberofhello. how can i do it.

Comment: @Ishrak you should raise another StackOverflow question with the details of what you want to do. But, given what you wrote in your comment, it already looks correct. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

You do

```
?- X = [hello,how,are,you,hello,hello], counthowmany(hello, X, N).
X = [hello, how, are, you, hello, hello],
N = 3.
```

First you first bind X ans then you ask for this specific X.

Example 2.

```
?- counthowmany(hello, X, N).
X = [],
N = 0.
```

Comment: X = [hello,hello,hello].

    counthowmany(_, [], 0) :- !.
    counthowmany(X, [X|Q], N) :- !, counthowmany(X, Q, N1), N is N1+1.
    counthowmany(X, [_|Q], N) :- counthowmany(X, Q, N).


this is my code in .pl file 
now i just want to ask question counthowmany(hello, X ,N).
but this can't be done ....... can you help me.....

Comment: Is it a problem that example 2 only gives one answer?

Comment: i don't want to use any list in the question ...... i just want to store a paragraph as a list in a variable and want to call that list for counting how many times a particular word appeared in that paragraph but when i do this "X = [hello,hello,hello]." and write the following code "counthowmany(_, [], 0) :- !.
counthowmany(X, [X|Q], N) :- !, counthowmany(X, Q, N1), N is N1+1.
counthowmany(X, [_|Q], N) :- counthowmany(X, Q, N)." and 

compile buffer i have a warning singleton variable:[X] and when i ask in prolog "counthowmany(hello,X,N)." the number of hello in the list doesn't shows

Comment: @Ishrak It's unclear what your problem is. If I take the code you listed in your comment and run `X=[hello,hello,hello], counthowmany(hello, X, N).` I get `N=3` and I don't see any singleton variable warnings. Perhaps you could update your problem statement (edit it) and indicate exactly what you tried and what the results were?

Comment: @mbratch
""L = [hello,hello,hello].

counthowmany(_, [], 0) :- !.
counthowmany(X, [X|Q], N) :- !, counthowmany(X, Q, N1), N is N1+1.
counthowmany(X, [_|Q], N) :- counthowmany(X, Q, N).""

    this is my code and 

counthowmany(hello,L,N).
 
     this is my question

Comment: @Ishrak you can't have a statement in your prolog file `L=[hello,hello,hello].` To prolog, you are attempting to redefine the `=/2` predicate. To indicate a fact for your list, you can have `my_list([hello,hello,hello]).` and then do something like, `my_list(L), counthowmany(hello,L,N).`