# how can i call prolog rule while asking prolog

Tags: prolog

```
my_list([hello,hello,hello])

counthowmany(_, [], 0) :- !.
counthowmany(X, [X|Q], N) :- !, counthowmany(X, Q, N1), N is N1+1.
counthowmany(X, [_|Q], N) :- counthowmany(X, Q, N).
```

in the code above if ask Prolog after compile buffer

```
my_list(L),counthowmany(hello,L,N).
```

this question then it gives me the number of hello.....

now if i modify the code in the following way

```
my_list([hello,hello,hello])

counthowmany(_, [], 0) :- !.
counthowmany(X, [X|Q], N) :- !, counthowmany(X, Q, N1), N is N1+1.
counthowmany(X, [_|Q], N) :- counthowmany(X, Q, N).

numberofhello :- my_list(L), counthowmany(hello,L,N).

% i. e. I want to insert the question in a rule
```

and after compile buffer (though i get a singleton variable warning) if i ask Prolog

```
numberofhello.
```

it just gives me "true" and i don't get the number of hello.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass a list in a predicate in prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971270/how-to-pass-a-list-in-a-predicate-in-prolog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the fact that your query (`numberofhello.`) does not have a variable (i.e. a "wh-word"), thus becomes "Can you count how many hellos?" yes-no question instead of "How many hellos". This should fix it:

```
numberofhello(N) :- my_list(L), counthowmany(hello, L, N).
```

With this,

```
?- numberofhello(N).
```

you should be getting your `N = 3`.