# creating a menu in prolog?

Tags: prolog

```
menu :-
    repeat,
    write('                          '),nl,
    write('   1.the number of hello  '),nl,
    write('                          '),nl,
    write('enter your choice:'),nl,
    read(Choice), Choice>0, Choice =<6,
    doit(Choice),Choice=6.


doit(1):- numberofhello(N).
doit(6):- abort.

my_list([hello,hello,hello]).


counthowmany(_, [], 0) :- !.
counthowmany(X, [X|Q], N) :- !, counthowmany(X, Q, N1), N is N1+1.
counthowmany(X, [_|Q], N) :- counthowmany(X, Q, N).


numberofhello(N) :- my_list(L),counthowmany(hello,L,N).
```

now in the code above after compile buffer when I ask Prolog for a menu the menu appears
with one choice and when i enter 1 for number of hello in the list(my_list) i don't get any answer and i get a singleton variable warning while compiling .....

can anyone help me please........

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass a list in a predicate in prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971270/how-to-pass-a-list-in-a-predicate-in-prolog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "singleton" variable is very similar, in other languages, to the warning, "Variable was assigned a value that is never used" or "A variable has been declared but never used". So your clause must do something with `N` in your first `doit` clause. You can also avoid the `doit(6) :- abort.` clause by allowing your `menu` to succeed without any choice points using a cut (`!`).

So, try:

```
menu :- repeat,
    write('                          '),nl,
    write('   1.the number of hello  '),nl,
    write('                          '),nl,
    write('enter your choice:'),nl,
    read(Choice), Choice>0, Choice =<6,
    doit(Choice), Choice=6, !.

doit(1):-
    numberofhello(N),
    write('Number of hello is = '), write(N), nl.
% Removed doit(6)...

...
```